# Lighttpd rewrite rules

Tags: regex, lighttpd

My rewrite doesn't work. I have my Lighttpd folder in my /etc directory, and my website in my /var/www directory. The following is in my configuration file:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "/var/www/website" {
     url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)" => "/home.php?username=$1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove your config above and instead add this (debug) row to the end of your lighttpd.conf (should work, but couldn't test it, sorry):

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^/(.*)$" => "/home.php?username=$1")
```

if it works, try to replace it with this:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "/var/www/website" {
   url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^/(.*)$" => "/home.php?username=$1")
}
```

of course you have "mod_rewrite" -server.module turned on at the start of the config file, right?